# How to proceed with debugging CPP legacy code?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-extensions

As new to this field I am not very sure what are the best technique/tools to debug a CPP, or MFC Code using Visual Studio. any experience folks please share.
*My question is more towards the tools like :
i) KlockWork extension
ii) setting the higher level warnings from properties.*

these are a few things that help me in debugging the code better way, is there any such extension, or features that we can use while debugging the code?

Comment: What does question even mean? If you are using Visual Studio, you just press Debug and it runs the debug process for you?

Comment: @Mecanik debug just does not mean pressing debug button, it's more about how you find the flow of data, transfer of controls and values passed, and many other aspects in order to find the desired bug/outcome?

Comment: Sorry... what? Everything you just mentioned here is visible with a click of a button in Visual Studio. Have you even tried it??

Comment: Debugging legacy code is no different from debugging any other code. You would use the same techniques and tools that you are using to debug your non-legacy code. Experience is the most valuable tool.

Answer (score 0):

A thorough tutorial on C++ debugging in various setups (CGG/Clang, MSVC/MinGW/WSL/Linux) can be found in [VSCode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug).

Also, I take a look at [C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

Comment: The question is asking about Visual Studio (which, unlike Visual Studio Code, actually comes with a debugger).

Comment: @IInspectable it is tagged as a Visual Studio Code question though. Need to flag that.

Comment: Visual Studio Code is a toy regardless, not a development environment, and certainly not a useful debugger, by any stretch.

Comment: @IInspectable Your comment is opinion-based and does not follow StackOverflow guidelines. 
It's not very useful either.

Comment: A "debugger" that doesn't allow one to inspect memory isn't actually a debugger. I doubt that classifies as an opinion.